# Jquery and click event

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, the elements are added to the page, but unusually the click event never fires. Any ideas?

```
function ToggleData(e) {
    var parentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var rowData = $(':nth-child(2)', parentRow);
    var html = $("<input type='text' id='amendedval' value='" + $.trim(rowData.text()) + "'/>");
    //Add the update tick
    var imgTick = $("<img src='../images/tick.png' id='imgTick'/>");
    rowData.text('');
    rowData.append(html);
    rowData.append(imgTick);
    imgTick.click(updateTickClick);
};

function updateTickClick(e) {
    alert('hi');
};
```

Comment: Could you use FireBug to check if rowData and parentRow are actually containing any DOM objects? (maybe the selectors return 0 elements)

Comment: The img is being added to the page correct with the correctdata.

Comment: try window.alert('hi') maybe ;-)

Comment: Interesting if I add the image to parentRow, and not rowData the click event fire's and i'm not sure as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed
var rowData = $(':nth-child(2)',parentRow);
To
var rowData = $('td:nth-child(2)',parentRow);

Now the click event is occuring correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
$("imgTick").onclick = updateTickClick;
```

I'm thinking the adding of an event handler may require an actual DOM reference rather than something built out of innerHTML.

--Edit

Looks like the problem is in your selecting of parentRow and rowData - here's my simplified example which works for me in both FF3.5 and IE7.  The only change is how rowData is selected:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing onclick</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleData(e){
        var rowData = $('td');
        var html = $("<input type='text' id='amendedval' value='" + $.trim(rowData.text()) +"'/>");
        //Add the update tick
        var imgTick = $("<img src='tick.png' id='imgTick'/>");
        rowData.text('');
        rowData.append(html);
        rowData.append(imgTick);
        imgTick.click(updateTickClick);
    };
    function updateTickClick(e) {
        alert('hi');
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="ToggleData(this); return false;">Click me</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still the same issue no event being fired.

Comment: He's using jQuery's click event binder(instead of the onclick DOM one). imgTick should be part of the DOM anyway, since it's appended to rowdata.

Comment: How about without the quotes around imgTick? I suggest you check out Firebug (http://getfirebug.com), its debugger is really useful for eliminating bugs like this.

Comment: OK, so 'imgTick = $("<img src='../images/tick.png' id='imgTick'/>");' is equivalent to 'document.createElement("IMG")'?  jQuery parses the string and then creates and returns a DOM element rather than inserting it into the document with innerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your imgTick is being added dynamically to the page.  Instead of using .click(), try using .live:

```
   imgTick.live("click", updateTickClick);
```

And, no, contrary to what [dhaval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119031/dhaval) said, it does **NOT** have to be anonymous.

Comment: that's what I thought but thought I would check.

Comment: He is binding the click after the element is added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgTick.bind("click", function(){
alert ( "Clicked" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be a callback registered with or without anonymous function

Comment: Why does it *need* to be? I thinks it's perfectly valid to pass a function reference.

Comment: An anonymous function is not required, function reference is perfectly legal.

Comment: Without live as Tony has pointed out , a function callback is required to register for events whose firing is unknown at start. needs be is changed to can be

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging in VS to see whats going on here. The information provided here seems incomplete to deduce anything. For a div with id imgTick, I would do this in jQuery for a click event :

```
$('#imgTick').click(function({

alert('Hi');
```

});

Comment: I think the selector used for getting the imgTick variable is incorrect? Shouldn't it be just $('#imgTick').